# How to fix : "IF" statements and adding return not working

Tags: swift, if-statement

Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type 'Bool'

Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

Expected '{' after 'if' condition

Expected ')' in expression list

Still a beginner, following a tutorial however this piece of code seems to be working fine for him and not for me. I am using Xcode 10 and I think he is using Xcode 8.

```
@IBAction func signupButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Sign up button tapped")

//Validating required texts are not empty
    if (firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
    (lastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
    (emailAddressTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
        (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||

    {
            return
    }

    if ((passwordTextField.text?.elementsEqual(reenterPasswordTextField.text! != true))
        {
    return
    }


}
```

The if statements are meant to link back to return/not tell to continue if text fields are not completed.

Comment: You don't need parentheses around each expression, ! should be before the condition but in this case you do not need them.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `elementsEqual` with a later `!= true`. The not-equal operator (`!=`) is much nicer: `if passwordTextField.text! != reenterPasswordTextField.text! { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues. This is your method cleaned up

```
@IBAction func signupButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Sign up button tapped")

    //Validating required texts are not empty
    if firstNameTextField.text!.isEmpty ||
        lastNameTextField.text!.isEmpty ||
        emailAddressTextField.text!.isEmpty ||
        passwordTextField.text!.isEmpty {
        return
    }

    if !passwordTextField.text!.elementsEqual(reenterPasswordTextField.text!) {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: To make this clear for newer members of the audience, using `text!` is safe because it is guaranteed that the `text` property of `UITextField` will never return `nil`, even if you set it to `nil`.

Comment: A bit advanced for a beginner, but it might be worth suggesting `if [firstNameTextField, lastNameTextField, emailAddressTextField, passwordTextField.text].contains(where: { $0.text!.isEmpty }) {`